# Two trigger to one function ? [keyup and focusout]

Tags: jquery, triggers

Welcome,

I have function

```
 $('#myfield').keyup(function () {
//do something
}
```

//- do something is runing when user write something in myfield.
I notice, when user use "auto complete"  from browser, my function is not executed.

I found idea, to use **focusout**

Do you have any idea how can i combine that code together, without writing second function like this ?

```
 $('#myfield').focusout(function () {
//do something
}
```

I would like to put this 2 functions together, and don't write //do something, two times.

regards

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) which takes a space separated list of events to bind your handler to, like this:

```
$('#myfield').bind("keyup focusout", function () {
  //do something
});
```

Though, unless you need some special propagation, I'd stick with [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) over `focusout`, just a preference really:

```
$('#myfield').bind("keyup blur", function () {
  //do something
});
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it! And Kudos to marc for thinking even at this stage of the "DRY" principle (don't repeat yourself)

Answer (score 1):

bind multiple events to input box

```
$('#myfield').bind("focusout",function(){

})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also write function seperately and give function name alone.. like...

```
$('#myfield').keyup(function_name).focusout (function_name);
function function_name() {
//do something
}
```